# Is there any way to order key values of a dictionary when appending them to a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

As of now I can append the key values of a dictionary to an empty list, but the goal is to print them in order of the keys in the dictionary.

Here's what I have so far:

```
DATA = {'Temp1':1, 'Temp2':2, 'RPM1':3, 'RPM2':4, 'Depth1':5, 'Depth2':6, 'A1':7, 'A2':8, 
'KWH1':9, 'KWH2':10, 'V1':11, 'V2':12}

vals = []

for value in DATA.itervalues():
    vals.append(value)

print vals
```

So I want to print the key value of 'Temp1', 'Temp2', 'RPM1', etc. in the specific order they're listed in the dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries **have no order**.

Comment: there is no order in dictionary, it is an unordered data structure.

Comment: You tagged your post with `ordereddictionary`, but are not using one. Perhaps you want to learn what it is: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: you can sort the keys by the values which will match the order of your DATA example  but that will only work as the values happen to ascend in line with the order you want your keys.